# Docker Process Management

Tags: docker, process-management

I have a deployed application running inside a Docker container, which is, in effect, an websocket client that runs forever. Every deploy I'm rebuilding the container and starting it with `docker run` using the command set in the `Dockerfile`.

Now, I've noticed a few times that the process occasionally dies without restarting. When running `docker ps`, I can see that the container is up, and has been up for 2 weeks, however the process running inside of it has died without the host being any the wiser

Do I need to go so far as to have a process manager inside of the docker container to manage the containerized process?

EDIT:

Dockerfile: https://github.com/DVG/catpen-edi/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?  If the websocket client is the only process running inside the container, then the container would exit immediately if that process exits.  If you are still the container in `docker ps`, that suggests you have something else running inside the container as well.

Comment: Updated question with a link to the dockerfile.

Comment: What else is running in the container when the websocket client has died?  You can run something like `docker exec <container_name_or_id> ps` to get a list of running processes in the container.

Comment: I've restarted the containers since it last died, but currently it shows 4 processes: sh, 2 rubies and ps. The two rubies makes sense, as the underlying process [spawns a child process](https://github.com/DVG/EDI/blob/master/lib/edi/cli.rb). If the child process died, though, I would expect the parent to finish and exit.

Comment: When you say "dies" what do you mean? If you have two ruby processes it sounds like the child hasn't exited, has it just stopped working?  Also do you need to use [two processes](https://github.com/DVG/EDI/blob/2d6c9803436097b61461baa9d56f01fef0c0639d/lib/edi/cli.rb#L17)? This only adds another layer between docker and your app. Try running `CMD [ "ruby", "boot.rb" ]` directly in Docker. You will also need to handle the `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` signals in your Ruby code.

Answer (score 3):

We've developed a process-manager tailor-made for Docker containers and have been using it with quite a bit of success to solve exactly the problem you describe.  The best starting point is to [take a look at chaperone-docker on github](https://github.com/garywiz/chaperone-docker).  The readme on the first page contains a quick link to a minimal base image as well as a fully configured LAMP stack so you can try it out and see what a fully-configured image would look like.   It's open-source and fully documented.

Comment: I'd be curious why anybody voted this down.  This is an exact solution for the poster's answer, it is open-source and took a lot of effort to solve exactly the problem the poster asked, and not a promotion by any commercial company.   I wish downvoters would give some constructive explanation for why they dislike a reasonable solution.

Comment: I'd imagine the down-votes are about self promotion.  I've given you an upvote though because I think what you've said is good advice, and your solution is good, but it's worth considering that your improvement on L0j1k's answer is not in the nature of answering the original question better, and your elucidation of the PID 1 problem is probably not better than that of baseimage-docker's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that mc0e.  Live and learn.  I'm getting there. :-)

Comment: @GaryWisniewski does chaperone have specific rules about what child processes a managed process should have?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting problem here related to PID1 and the fact that docker replaces PID1 with the command specified in `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. What's happening is that the child process isn't automagically adopted by anything if the parent dies and it becomes an orphan (since there is no PID1 in the sense of a traditional init system like you're used to). [Here is some excellent reading](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) to give you a few ideas. You may get some mileage out of their [`baseimage-docker`](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) image which comes with their simplified init system ("my_app"), which will solve some of this problem for you. However, I would strongly caution you against automatically adopting the Phusion mindset for all of your containers, as there exists some ideological friction in that space. I can't recall any discussion on Docker's Github about a potential minimal init system to solve this problem, but I can't imagine it will be a problem forever. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two ruby processes it sounds like the child hasn't exited, the application has just stopped working. It's likely the EventMachine reactor is sitting in the background.

Does the EDI app really need to [spawn the additional Ruby process](https://github.com/DVG/EDI/blob/2d6c9803436097b61461baa9d56f01fef0c0639d/lib/edi/cli.rb#L17)? This only adds another layer between Docker and your app. Run the server directly with `CMD [ "ruby", "boot.rb" ]`. If you find the problem still occurs with a single process then you will need to find what is causing your app to hang.

When a process is running as PID 1 is docker it will need [handle the `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM`](https://gist.github.com/sauloperez/6592971) signals too.

```
# Trap ^C 
Signal.trap("INT") { 
  shut_down 
  exit
}

# Trap `Kill `
Signal.trap("TERM") {
  shut_down
  exit
}
```

Docker also has [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) for when the container does actually die.

```
docker run --restart=always
```

> - `no`
>     Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is
>     the default.
> - `on-failure[:max-retries]`
>     Restart only if the container
>     exits with a non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of
>     restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.
> - `always`
>     Always restart the
>     container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the
>     Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The
>     container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the
>     current state of the container.
> - `unless-stopped`
>     Always restart the
>     container regardless of the exit status, but do not start it on daemon
>     startup if the container has been put to a stopped state before.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I did want to point out that the question was talking about an zombie container where the container was running but the process had died.